# C# getter and setter returns null when adding validation

Tags: c#

I'm implementing getters and setters on my code but I'm having trouble with my getter and setter, it always returns null when using a code for validation in the setter, Here's my code:

```
private string _employeeId;

public string EmployeeId
{
    get
    {
        return this._employeeId
    }
    set
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this._employeeId))
        {
            this._employeeId = value;
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee ID is required");
        }
    }  
}
```

and in my application, I assign the value of _employeeId by
creating an object of the class

```
 Employees obj = new Employees();

 obj.EmployeeId = txt_empId.Text;
```

Comment: Presumably, you meant to validate `value`. Otherwise `_employeeId` would always be null, so it would always fail the validation and therefore never get assigned.

Comment: U r doing it opposite way make get as set n vice versa

Answer (score 5):

The setter is trying to set the local variable but will never set it because `IsNullOrEmpty(this._employeeId)` returns `true`, preventing it from ever being set. Perhaps you meant to check `IsNullOrEmpty` on `value`??

Answer (score -2):

In your code the variable `_employeeId` is empty, because you do not set a initial value for it. and in set method you are validation `_employeeId` variable, so this result always is null, then throw the Exception! i think you want to validation a value what is set method input value. So you must validation variable `value`, instead of variable `_employeeId`!

```
private string _employeeId;

public string EmployeeId
{
    get
    {
        return this._employeeId
    }
    set
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            this._employeeId = value;
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception("Employee ID is required");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: maybe I need to study more to learn this language, thanks for the help!

Comment: yeah, just go ahead!

Comment: @JohanShen: Though this code does fix the problem, it's best to explain *what* you changed and *why* so it's clear to everyone how this fixes the problem. You may want to read [answer] for more information.